# Visual studio pre build event

Tags: visual-studio, cmd, pre-build-event

Im running the following command in my pre build event

```
(get-content "$(SolutionDir)woop.txt") -replace 'HELLO','GOODBYE' | set-content "$(SolutionDir)woop.txt"
```

however im getting the following error:

The command `"(get-content "C:\Users\jonny\Desktop\data\a\woop.txt") -replace 'HELLO','GOODBYE' | set-content "C:\Users\jonny\Desktop\data\a\woop.txt""` exited with code 255.

Any one got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build events scripts are dos script based, not PowerShell...

I suggest you to wrap your script in a ps1 file, then executing powershell.Exe with the proper arguments.

**EDIT**

This [article](http://davidfrette.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/creating-powershell-pre-build-and-post-build-events-for-visual-studio-projects/) shows how to do it.

Comment: any idea how you do that? never used a ps1 file or powershell.exe before